# Induced residue field extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, local-field, ramification

Let $K$ be a local field with ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ and residue field $\kappa_K$. Let $f(x)$ be a monic irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathcal{O}_K[x]$. Let $L=K[x]/ (f(x))$. As a result of Hensel's lemma, we have that the reduction $\overline{f}(x)$ factors as $g_0(x)^e$ for some monic irreducible $g_0(x)$ in $\kappa_K[x$]. I am trying to prove that $\kappa_L = \kappa_K[x]/ (g_0(x))$.

I see why $\kappa_L$ contains $\kappa_K[x]/ (g_0(x))$. If $e=1$, then I can use the fact that
\begin{align*}
n=[\kappa_K[x]/(g_0(x)):\kappa_K] \leq [\kappa_L:\kappa_K]\leq n 
\end{align*}
to conclude that $\kappa_L = \kappa_K[x]/ (g_0(x))$. But if $e>1$ then I am a bit stuck. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As you stated it is not true, try with $K=Q_3,L=Q_3(i), f= x^2+3^2$ then $f\equiv x^2 \bmod 3$ but the residue field is $F_3(i)=F_9$.
- Let $O_K$ a complete DVR with finite residue field and unique maximal ideal $(\pi_K)$ and $L/K$ a finite extension.

  $v(b) =  \frac1{[L:K]}v(N_{L/K}(b))$  extends the valuation to $L$, let $O_L=\{ b\in L,v(b)\ge 0\}$

  Claim : $O_L$ is monogenic $O_L=O_K[a]=O_K[x]/(f)$

  $f = \prod_j f_j^{e_j}\bmod (\pi_K)$

  each $(\pi_K,f_j)$ is a maximal ideal of $O_L$

  let $\pi_L$ an element of minimal positive valuation in $O_L$

  $(\pi_L)$ is the unique maximal of $O_L$ which means $(\pi_K,f_j)=(\pi_L)=(\pi_K,f_1)$ ie. $f_1\equiv f_j\bmod \pi_K$ ie. $f = f_1^e\bmod (\pi_K)$

  and $O_L$'s residue field is $$O_L/(\pi_L)=O_L/(\pi_K,f_1) = O_K[x]/(f)/(\pi_K,f_1) =O_K/(\pi_K)[x]/(f_1)$$

Comment: Ah thanks for sharing the counterexample. When you say $(\pi_K,f_j)$ is maximal in $\mathcal{O}_L$, I'm sort of confused. Isn't $f_j$ a polynomial, not an element of $\mathcal{O}_L$?

Comment: Obviously $(\pi_K,f_j(x))$ is a maximal ideal of $O_K[x]/(f(x))$

Comment: Why is $O_L$ monogenic? Still struggling with this part

Comment: The residue field of $O_L$ is $F_{p^f}$, because $O_L$ is a complete DVR then $\zeta_{p^f-1}\in O_L$, let $a=\zeta_{p^f-1}(1+\pi_L)$ then $O_L = O_K[\zeta_{p^f-1},\pi_L]= O_K[a]$. Proof : $O_L = \{ \sum_{n\ge 0} c_n \pi_L^n, c_n\in \{\zeta_{p^f-1}^j\}\cup 0\}= \sum_{m=0}^{e-1}\pi_L^m \sum_j \zeta_{p^f-1}^j O_K $  and $v(a^{p^f-1}-1)= v(\pi_L)=1/e$.